# Why is my function sometimes squaring twice?

Tags: javascript

Writing a function to take a number, square each number and return them as a concatenated integer, ie. 3214 => 94116. For some reason, my code appears to occasionally square 2's and 3's twice making a 2 turn into 16 and 3 into 81. I can't figure it out. I'm not a super experienced debugger yet so any help would be appreciated.

```js
function squareDigits(num){
  let digits = (""+num).split("");
  let intDigits = [];
  
  for (x of digits) {
    intDigits.push(parseInt(x));
  }
  
  for (x of intDigits) {
    intDigits.splice(intDigits.indexOf(x), 1, x * x);
  }
 
  return parseInt(intDigits.join(""));
}

console.log(squareDigits(24));
```

Comment: Because `intDigits.indexOf(x)` is the _first_ index where `x` is found, so `squareDigits(24)` finds the `2` at index 0, replaces it by `4`, then finds the `4` at index 0 again, not at index 1. Why not simply do `const squareDigits = (num) => Array.from(String(num), (digit) => digit ** 2).join("");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that you can do this more elegantly with something like `map()` the issue in your code is that it uses `indexOf()` while changing the values on each iteration. Since `indexOf()` returns the index of the first occurrence it is going to find digits that you have already replaced.

This is your original code with a few logs so you can understand what I mean:

```js
function squareDigits(num){
  let digits = (""+num).split("");
  let intDigits = [];
  
  for (x of digits) {
    intDigits.push(parseInt(x));
  }
  
  for (x of intDigits) {
    console.log('intDigits: ' + intDigits);
    console.log(` index of ${x} = ${intDigits.indexOf(x)}`);
    intDigits.splice(intDigits.indexOf(x), 1, x * x);
  }
 
  return parseInt(intDigits.join(""));
}

console.log('RESULT: ' + squareDigits(24));
```

Notice how in the second pass the index of `4` is `0` (the first position in the array) because you have replaced the original `2` by it's squared value `4`.

A simple way to fix this is to not rely on `indexOf()` and iterate over the array the good old way, like this:

```js
function squareDigits(num){
  let digits = (""+num).split("");
  let intDigits = [];
  
  for (x of digits) {
    intDigits.push(parseInt(x));
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < intDigits.length; i++) {
    const x = intDigits[i];
    console.log('intDigits: ' + intDigits);
    console.log(` index of ${x} = ${i}`);
    intDigits.splice(i, 1, x * x);
  }
  
  return parseInt(intDigits.join(""));
}

console.log('RESULT: ' + squareDigits(24));
```

Comment: Thank you. The other solutions people have posted are great I'm just not experienced enough to understand them properly. Thanks for breaking it down and providing a solution using my method.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic (and bug free) version of your function could be this:

```js
const squareDigits = num => [...num.toString()].map(x => x ** 2).join('');

console.log(squareDigits(24));
```

Other variant:

```js
const squareDigits = num => num.toString().replaceAll(/\d/g, x => x ** 2);

console.log(squareDigits(24));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping twice use array methods `.map() , .reduce() etc` it will make your code effective .. wrote a simple function

See =>

```
   function squareDigits(num){
   let digits = String(num).split("");
    digits =  digits.reduce((final , digit)=> final += String( parseInt(digit) **2 ), "");
   return digits
   }

  console.log(squareDigits(312));
```

Answer (score -1):

As [@Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68198082/why-is-my-function-sometimes-squaring-twice/68198178#comment120531264_68198082) mentioned, `intDigits.indexOf(x)` will find the
first index. So after replacing the first one, there's a change you'll find the number you've just replaced.

---

We can simplify the function to :

```js
function squareDigits(num){
  return num.toString().split('').map(n => n ** 2).join('');
}
```

Where :

- We convert the number to a string using [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)
- We split the string into loose numbers using [`split('')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over each number
- Return the square by using the [Exponentiation (`**`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation) operator
- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the numbers to get the result

Example snippet:

```js
function squareDigits(num){
  return num.toString().split('').map(n => n ** 2).join('');
}

console.log(squareDigits(3214));   // 94116
```